# Panasonic Toughbook won't turn on

Tags: motherboard, power

A Panasonic Toughbook, model CF-W8, fails to start.  By mistake I tried to turn it on through another laptop charger which provides higher voltage; the Toughbook only uses 16 V.

Comment: There are simple things to try first.

Does it try to launch the BIOS at boot? If it shows the BIOS start screen but fails to start your operating system, it could be the hard drive or the OS. 

What do you see when it tries to boot?  Please describe.

Will it start without the power supply, running on battery only?

Will it start without the battery, running on external power only?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, over voltage can fry any electronics, including a PC.